# Android, exception in non-ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, user-interface

Is there anyway that I could set the DDMS, so that it could capture exceptions from non-ui thread in eclipse? It took me long enough to realize that if an exception occur in non-ui thread, the program won't be effected much, at least in my case. Basically I have the following code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         A.errorMethod();
    }
}).start();
```

When I run the app,it just halt while doing errorMethod, but there is no exception message shown. After I took the A.errorMethod(); part out and run it directly, I got the exception message in Logcat, weird.

Comment: uh - it will capture non-ui exceptions.  more likely your code is swallowing the exception in a try-catch block or something.

Comment: When you say it is not capturing them do you mean that they are not showing up in logcat?

Comment: yes, the exception are not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

try to let the debugger bind to the thread using:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         Debug.waitForDebugger();
         A.errorMethod();
    }
}).start();
```